# Compare Kotlin data classes with double members

Tags: kotlin, equals, data-class

In Kotlin you can compare two instances of the same data class just by doing something like

```
if(dataClassInstance1 == dataClassInstance2) ...
```

which is very nice and handy.
But what is the way to go, if the data class contains a member of type "Double"(Kotlin).
Comparing two doubles by "==" is a big no no, as everyone knows.

Do I have to override the equals() method do realize a working comparison by == ?

Comment: `==` on doubles could be fine, depending on how you are using the class.

Comment: currently I'm just storing some calculated values in the class. I'm using the compare indirectly in a test case via "assertEquals"

Comment: This [blog](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/equality-in-kotlin-and-equals-d8373ef529f1) provides a lot of context. But no answer.

Comment: The [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#floating-point-numbers-comparison) add some context as well.

Comment: Comparing two doubles by `==` uses the _only_ reasonable definition of `==` for doubles, even if it's not a good definition.  Anything else would be _worse._

Comment: If you need more than strict equality, you might want to check whether you should be using some other type or representation.  (As Louis indicates, redefining `==` to do range checks or whatever will lead to tears before cocoa, as it'll break part of the contract — probably transitivity.)

Comment: Okay, finally I found the time to reply.
Yes the comparison with "==" works, I've made another mistake. Sorry!